# Criar heatmap de um campo de futebol com heatmap.js

Tags: javascript, heatmap.js

Estou precisando criar um mapa de calor com um campo de futebol, porém, não estou conseguindo...

Estou utilizando o heatmap.js ([neste link](https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/)), porém, não estou conseguindo...

Já segui o passo-a-passo que é dado no repositório, mas não deu certo...

Atualmente o meu código segue desta forma:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mapa de calor do jogo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="heatmap/build/heatmap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Mapa de calor do campo</h4>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var config = {
            container: document.getElementById('heatmapContainer'),
            radius: 10,
            maxOpacity: .5,
            minOpacity: 0,
            blur: .75
        };
        // create heatmap with configuration
        var heatmapInstance = h337.create(config);
        // a single datapoint
        var dataPoint = {
            x: 5, // x coordinate of the datapoint, a number
            y: 5, // y coordinate of the datapoint, a number
            value: 100 // the value at datapoint(x, y)
        };
        heatmapInstance.addData(dataPoint);

// multiple datapoints (for data initialization use setData!!)
        var dataPoints = [dataPoint, dataPoint, dataPoint, dataPoint];
        heatmapInstance.addData(dataPoints);

        var data = {
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
            data: [
                dataPoint, dataPoint, dataPoint, dataPoint
            ]
        };
        heatmapInstance.setData(data);
    }
</script>
<div id="heatmapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém já teve o mesmo problema? Ou consegue me dar uma luz de onde pode estar o problema?

O arquivo `JS` utilizado, é o mesmo que está no repositório que postei o link.

Posteriormente, os dados para o heatmap virá da `API` da footstats.

Comment: 1 - você já verificou se os arquivos do heatmap estão em heatmap/build/heatmap.js assim como indica na tag script? O erro diz que esses arquivos não estão presentes em seu projeto. 2 - escolha uma das formas, apresentadas no seu exemplo, para criar o dataPoint. Após conseguir com apenas um aplique os demais exemplos.